# From Pandas groupBy to PySpark groupBy

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

Consider an Spark DataFrame, wherein we have few columns. The goal is to perform groupBy operation on it without converting it to Pandas DataFrame. An equivalent Pandas groupBy code looks something like this:

```
def compute_metrics(x):
    return pd.Series({
        'a': x['a'].values[0],
        'new_b': np.sum(x['b']),
        'c': np.mean(x['c']),
        'cnt': len(x)
    })

data.groupby([
    'col_1',
    'col_2'
]).apply(compute_metrics).reset_index()
```

And I'm intending to write this in PySpark. So far I have come up with something like this in `PySpark`:

```
gdf = df.groupBy([
    'col_1',
    'col_2'
]).agg({
    'c': 'avg',
    'b': 'sum'
}).withColumnRenamed('sum(b)', 'new_b')
```

However, I am not sure how to go about `'a': x['a'].values[0]` and `'cnt': len(x)`. I thought about using `collect_list` from `from pyspark.sql import functions` but that slaps my face with `Column object is not Callable`. Any idea how to accomplish the aforementioned conversion? Thanks!

**[UPDATE]** Would it make sense to perform `count` operation on **any** column in order to get `cnt`? Say I do this:

```
gdf = df.groupBy([
    'col_1',
    'col_2'
]).agg({
    'c': 'avg',
    'b': 'sum',
    'some_column': 'count'
}).withColumnRenamed('sum(b)', 'new_b')
  .withColumnRenamed('count(some_column)', 'cnt')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have this toy solution using PySpark function `sum`, `avg`, `count` and `first`. **note** that I use Spark 2.1 in this solution. Hope this help a bit!

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum, avg, count, first

# create toy example dataframe with column 'A', 'B' and 'C'
ls = [['a', 'b',3], ['a', 'b', 4], ['a', 'c', 3], ['b', 'b', 5]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(ls, schema=['A', 'B', 'C'])

# group by column 'A' and 'B' then performing some function here
group_df = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])
df_grouped = group_df.agg(sum("C").alias("sumC"), 
                          avg("C").alias("avgC"), 
                          count("C").alias("countC"), 
                          first("C").alias("firstC"))
df_grouped.show() # print out the spark dataframe
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution is more elegant than my ugly snippet. I am still wondering what to do with `'a': x['a'].values[0]`.

Comment: What is `values[0]` in this case @KevinGhaboosi? Is it the first element of grouped by?

Comment: Just to note here. For more complicated function, you can write UDF (user defined function) in order to apply after group by.

Comment: Thank you @titipat for the comment. Yes. That is correct!

Comment: Is there a way to have an equivalent to pandas `apply()` in that the whole sub dataframe can be passed through and manipulated by another function?